# WITH - SELECT statement with multiple conditions (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl

select statement in VHDL that assigns the same signal in more than one case:
`with ALUop select
   z <= s_add_sub   when "00000",
        s_add_sub   when "00001",
        s_add_sub   when "00010",
        s_add_sub   when "00011",
        x AND y     when "00100",
        x OR y      when "00101",
        x XOR y     when "00110",
        lhi         when "00111",
        seq         when "01000",
        sne         when "01001",
        slt         when "01010",
        sgt         when "01011",
        sle         when "01100",
        sge         when "01101",
        NOT x       when "01110",
        x           when "01111",
        shift_out   when "10000",
        shift_out   when "10001",
        shift_out   when "10010",
        y           when "10011",
        x"00000000" when others;`


How can I change the statement so the assignment is made in only one line for multiple conditions, something like:

`with ALUop select
   z <= s_add_sub   when "00000" OR "00001" OR "00010" OR "00011",...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `|` and not `OR` for multiple choices, thus making code like:

```
with ALUop select 
  z <= s_add_sub when "00000" | "00001" | "00010" | "00011", 
       x AND y when "00100", 
       ...
```

This is similar to the syntax for multiple choices to `case`.

Comment: Great thank you, I didn't even know VHDL uses the | operataor.

Comment: Can I use the | operator in a basic conditional signal assignment statement like: z <= s_add_sub when ALUop = "00000" | "00001" | "00010" | "00011" else...

Comment: No, the `|` is a separator like `,`, not an operator like `OR`.